Is these two regex checker are different /\S+/g (capital "S") and /\s+/g?
function wordCount(val) {
  var wom = val.match(/\S+/g);
  return {
    charactersNoSpaces: val.replace(/\s+/g, '').length,
    characters: val.length,
    words: wom ? wom.length : 0,
    lines: val.split(/\r*\n/).length
  };
}

I am just asking, they both behaving totally opposite.

That’s a different pattern!

\S matches non-whitespace characters, \s matches whitespace characters. So wom is an array of all the words.

in general, lowercase and uppercase are each other's opposites. \w is word character, \W is "not a word character", \d is digit, \D is "not a digit", \s is white space, \S is "not white space".
